# How to automatically close the Login window after logged into the homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried `window.close()` function,its works perfectly for IE but not in Chrome and Firefox. In IE the login page will automatically close but in other browsers the login page remains and the home page will open in the new tab. Can anyone have the solution for this? the Function I used to close the new tab is given below

```
function quitBox(cmd)
{
    if (cmd == 'quit') {
        var rand_no = Math.round(1000 * Math.random());

        if (window.name == "IMSWindowName") {
            windowName = "IMSWindowNameFirst" + rand_no;
            windowName = "_self" + rand_no;
        } else {
            windowName = "IMSWindowName" + rand_no;
            windowName = "_self" + rand_no;
        }
        heightVal = screen.height - 150;
        widthVal = screen.width - 150;

        newwin2 = window.open('', windowName, 'toolbar=no,status=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,top=0,left=0,height=' + heightVal + ',width=' + widthVal + '');
        document.forms[0].target = windowName;
        document.forms[0].action = 'LogIn';
        document.forms[0].method = 'post';
        newwin2.focus();
        window.opener = 'X';
        window.open('', '_parent', '');
        var oldURL = document.referrer;
        window.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the Login window after login then

open the Login Window as a Child Window

then u can close it from its parent

```
newwin2 = window.open('',"muk",'toolbar=no,status=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,top=0,left=0,height='+100+',width='+100+'');
setTimeout(function(){ newwin2.close() }, 3000);
```

Comment: tested on chrome - open the chrome dev console paste these 2 line